# UIScrollview with Paging (AutoLayout) issue

Tags: ios7, uiscrollview, autolayout, paging

I have a UIScrollview which has One **contentView** in contentView and it has **Three** views which are Statically created on the Storyboard. I have Enabled paging from Storyboard for Scrollview with AutoLayout Enabled. **View1,view2 and view3** widths are 568 (Landscape),  which is working Perfectly in iPhone 5 but when I Run on 3.5 inches devices its not adopting the Size of the Screen. 
How should i manage this issue ? Thanks.